# Redirecting hotspot's traffic through the TOR

Tags: iptables, proxy, wifi, access-point, tor

I have settled WI-FI hotspot on Kali linux via `hostapd+dnsmasq` tools. For being able to access internet(which is accessible through different interface) I used masquerading:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But afterward another feature turned to be wanted: redirection of the incoming traffic to the tor's proxy. Could you help me to understand which rules I need to append to iptables in order to proxying through tor configured like this:

```
# configure tor with this configuration
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 10.0.0.1
DNSPort 5354
DNSListenAddress 10.0.0.1
SOCKSPort 0
```

Comment: @Michael_Hampton, my question is not about "blocking all except tor`s traffic"

Comment: Did you actually read the answer? Everything you need is there.

Comment: I noticed that your variant demands static IP`s on host. Is there variant for intranet? Or can you reopen the question pls? @Michael_Hampton

Comment: You only need a static IP on your LAN side. If you're setting up your own AP with hostapd then this is something you should have already done. And, the rest of your questions are really out of scope here.